# Firebase Crash Reporting: Failed to transmit crash: Error 403

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Did anyone tried new Firebase Crash reporting?

I am stuck with following error after creating a crash .

> CrashReporter[4248:]  Firebase Analytics enabled
>   2016-05-27 09:22:07.579 CrashReporter[4248:68995] Firebase Crash Reporting: Failed to transmit crash: Error Domain=com.google.FirebaseCrash Code=1 "Upload failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Upload failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=HTTP **Error Code 403**:  {

Comment: I was following  google steps:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios

Answer (score 4):

This occurs when you have a missing or incorrect API_KEY, which is read out of your GoogleService-Info.plist file.  I would check the following:

1) Confirm your GoogleService-Info.plist file contains an API_KEY.  There is a rare bug where you can download the file and this field is not inserted.  If the API_KEY is missing, download a new GoogleService-Info.plist file (click on your project, click the gear icon in the upper left of the screen, click project settings, select your app, and download a new config file).

2) Confirm you're using the correct GoogleService-Info.plist file.  If you setup two projects, make sure both projects are using different files, and they aren't mixed up.

3) Make sure your GoogleService-Info.plist file wasn't renamed to something like GoogleService-Info.plist (1) by your web browser. If it was, rename it back to GoogleService-Info.plist

**Edit:**  This can also be due to a CFBundleVersion or CFBundleShortVersionString not being a major.minor.patch, all numeric.  The restriction on CFBundleVersion is getting dropped soon (along with a better error message)

Comment: I have the setup as you described.but still i got the "Upload failed" with HTTP Error Code 403 error.

Comment: Thanks, changing the version string to be major.minor.patch, all numeric fixed the problem.

Comment: Ty, in my case the API_KEY was missing indeed. Added it ; works now.