# Firebase Crash Reporting error: client application com.xxxx are blocked

Tags: android, firebase, http-status-code-403, firebase-crash-reporting

I have implemented FCM and Firebase analytics with success in my project but I found an error trying with Firebase crash reporting and I don't have any idea what I'm missing.

I'm just trying to use Firebase crash reporting following [the official tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android) and getting this error:
[image]
It said:

> Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: Requests from this Android client application com.xxxxxx **are blocked**.

After dig in google and here (stack overflow), I found some related questions (
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37393218/1332549),
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41169250/1332549),
[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37484755/1332549)) but none of their solutions work for me. I mean, someone talk about check API_KEY, someone else talk about check crash report enabled in console and the list keep going. I have tried those answers before posting this question.

**update:** Explaining a little bit for those didn't want to look above links: I tried updating the google-services.json file changing the API_KEY, deleting and adding again SHA1, leaving API_KEY empty, etc. Downloading the google-services.json file for each change I did with no luck.

My API_KEY in my google-services.json file looks like:

```
"api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxzxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "current_key": "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
```

And I checked that my google-service.json has debug and release SHA1.

**update**
The weird thing is that I'm getting reports in Analytics section, as you can see in next screenshot:
[image]

Looking the project in [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/) I found that I have Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API **enabled** (like you can see in the follow screenshot):
[image]
After clicking in "Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API" I got this:
[image]
The image above shows 2 images: all traffic to "Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API" done and the errors processed by the API. As you can see it said that all my request were **403 Error** (you can see it where it said 403:0.0004): and that's true, I've tried 4 times and all time I got same console error.

**No idea what is going on or what I'm missing**

If you need info about gradle app file to help me, here is:

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
>     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
>     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:10.0.1'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue, solved it by setting the API key `Key restriction` in Google Console to `NONE`.

Comment: I like you was my problem. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Thanks man! So helpful. Would have never found that mistake myself. Was trying to add Firebase In-App messaging to my app, but this service didn't pass the package name to the API, so the restriction which I have set in the past blocked the request.

Comment: This answer works but if you're supposed to set the bundleId to the **Key restriction > Application restrictions** what is the purpose of it if only **NONE** works?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, resolved it by download a new configuration file `google-services.json`.

Comment: I tried it, tried changing API_KEY inside file, tried adding dev SHA1 in project with no luck

Comment: I have realize crash reporting is working in release version but not in dev version

Comment: Maybe you only added the API_KEY for the release version and not the debug version?

Comment: @RosarioPereiraFernandes That was one of the things that I tried, I mean, remove release and debug key and added both again, downloaded google-service.json again... no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems and I tried dropping the gradle levels, which helped me because of some stability issues in the newest ones.

to:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:9.2.1'
```

also you sdk to :

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cloud.savari.example.com.fcm"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: but I can't drop down levels because I'm using [setCurrentScreen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setCurrentScreen(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) witch is available since 9.8

Comment: Then I would suggest you drop it down as much as you can and then retry. I went down to `9.2.1` and not lesser than that because of `locations and FCM` try playing around with the versions but make sure that `play-services and firebase` are on the same version.