# Firebase phone Authentication failes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to do Firebase Login using Phone Auth.
As I am developing and I don't have an access to device & Apple developer account, so I went to implement this feature using

> reCAPTCHA verification

but I get this following error

> {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from this ios client
>   application  are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests from
>   this ios client application  are
>   blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}

I have implemented that as it has been shown in the documentation.

Below is the code from AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}

// For iOS 9+
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
        return true
    }
    return false
    // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
}
```

Below is the code from ViewController.swift:

```
@IBAction func didTapSignUp(_ sender: Any) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+919637892151", uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationId, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // It always comes here
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let verificationId = verificationId {
            print(verificationId)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationId, forKey: "authVerificationID")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Cordova as well?

Comment: Nope, pure Swift

Comment: Please update your question to include the associated code and google plist file so that we can try to assist

Comment: @Jake I have added the code from AppDelegate and ViewController file.

Comment: Have you added the custom URL schemes in your app configuration and the google plist file?

Comment: @Jake Yes I had added.

Comment: @Jake will this work on simulator.

Comment: It should. It sounds like your plist and your url schemes aren’t right. You’re getting an error saying you don’t have permission to venture to that url. Re-read the documentation and check that part step by step

Comment: It may be some restrictions in your API key. Try to check that in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: It has something to do with the bundleId, works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42695845/4833705) and it works.

"set the API key Key restriction in Google Console to NONE"

I'm perplexed though because what is the purpose of it if only NONE works?

Comment: This is not the correct solution. You shouln't remove your key security. Unfortunately there is not a clean solution because it looks like a Google Auth issue.

Comment: @FrizzTheSnail "This is not the correct solution" and "Unfortunately there is not a clean solution" doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: @FrizzTheSnail From Google Docs: "*This flow also requires your **API Key to be unrestricted** or allowlisted*". Read the reCAPTCHA section https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth. Even Google itself says it.